# Second derivative exist but first derivative zero

Tags: calculus

Can there be any function $f(x)$ (periodic or nonperiodic) with $f'(x)=0$ but $f''(x) \neq 0$. Is it possible!!

Comment: Do you mean $f^{'}$ is identically zero or 0 only at a point $x$?

Comment: What if f'(x)=0 for all x?

Comment: By the way, there is a huge difference between saying that X "exists" and saying that $X\neq0$, so be careful with that! For example, if $f(x)=2x$, then the second derivative exists *and* equals zero.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean with $f'(x)$ *identically* equal to $0$ (that is, $0$ everywhere), then no, since $f''(x)$ will then readily be identically $0$, too.

Otherwise, yes. For example, let $f(x)=\cos x.$ Then $f'(x)=0$ exactly when $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi,$ but $f''(x)=\pm 1$ for all such $x$.

Answer (score 0):

No, a simple observation is think of the geometric interpretation of the second derivative. It represents the concavity or curvature. If $f^{'}(x) = 0$ then $f(x) = c$ and clearly there is zero curvature or concavity for a constant function.

Comment: Assuming of course you mean $f^{'}(x) = 0$ for all $x$.